# Getting absolute path on Server in PHP

Tags: php

I want absolute path of the a file starting from

```
http://...../file.jpg.
```

But instead m getting something like

```
\/home\/abc\/public_html\/def\\file.JPG
```

Also dont know the reason for "/"
The code am using is

```
dirname(__FILE__)."\\file.jpg"
```

Any help please?

Comment: You should concatenate the url with http path of the uplaoded file, what you are referring to, is the directory path of file.

Comment: But what about public_html\/def which are coming in between?

Comment: there must be some php inbuilts(which am not aware) to get absolute path on server or at least through concatenating it should work. But dont know what that is!!

Comment: `public_html` is the public directory of your application. If the image is inside the `def` folder the url will be `'http://example.com' . "/def/$file"`

Comment: working fine for me....

Comment: What about home? That is not a folder

Comment: In fact it is, that's the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$path = substr( __FILE__, strlen( $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] ) );
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$path;
```

Comment: How to refer to file other than current file? i.e. my current file is current.php but i want absolute path of folder/file.jpg?

Answer (score 0):

This works with `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']`. Just concatenate the result with your domain name:

```
$domain = 'http://www.example.com' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
```

**[$_SERVER Variables](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php)**